# How to fill array from index to another index in Python

Tags: python, arrays

How to fill an array from on index let's say 3 to 5 in an array containing 10 element **without** **a for loop**?

Input:

```
[0,5,8,4,6,7,5,1,3,0]
```

Output:

```
[0,5,8,'replaced','replaced','replaced',5,1,3,0]
```

Comment: abc[3:6] = 666. That's it.

Comment: @pissall That won't work with an `int` but `abc[3:6] = '666'` would

Comment: I assumed it's a numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

Since lists are mutable, you can just use list slicing:

```
>>> lst = [0,5,8,4,6,7,5,1,3,0]
>>> lst[3:6] = ['','','']
>>> lst
[0, 5, 8, '', '', '', 5, 1, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
arr = [0,5,8,4,6,7,5,1,3,0]

arr[3:6] = ['replaced']*(6-3)
# [0, 5, 8, 'replaced', 'replaced', 'replaced', 5, 1, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it

```
>>> nums = [0,5,8,4,6,7,5,1,3,0]
>>> ['replaced' if 3 <= i <= 5 else num for i, num in enumerate(nums)]
[0, 5, 8, 'replaced', 'replaced', 'replaced', 5, 1, 3, 0]
```